# Photoelectric effect and space charge

Tags: electrons, photoelectric-effect

I recently studied about photoelectric effect. My online teacher said about space charge that- after the photoelectrons are released from the cathode they accumulate near the cathode stopping other electrons to go and reach the cathode. My question is that why is the space charge of electron cloud is created. even somehow it is then why are they not accelerated by the potential difference?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a single (gas phase) atom. When an electron leaves an orbital due to excitation by a photon, it leaves behind a positive hole.

Move to a bulk material standing by itself in a vacuum. The hole created when the photo-electron leaves is initially localized in the orbital. In the time that the photo-electron is leaving, the hole can also delocalize in the bulk material. The extent that the hole delocalizes depends on the nature of the orbital. As a function of excitation energy (frequency of the light), the first states that are photo-excited are the valence states of lowest energy. A valence band orbital in a metal is more delocalized than a valence band orbital in a semiconductor because the former is from metallic bonding and the latter is from covalent bonding.

Let's stay with valence-band photo-emission for the moment.

As valence-band photo-electrons leave a bulk material in a vacuum, the holes left behind are delocalized throughout the material to more or less extent depending on the nature of the valence orbitals. Since the material is in a vacuum, no electrons are added to it to make up for the depletion of photo-electrons. The photo-excited material becomes net positively charged. This bulk positive charge has the same effect as shifting the Fermi energy relative to the vacuum state. We need more energy to pull an electron from a positively charged material than from a neutral material. At some point in time, the photoemission will stop.

The above can be generalized to core-hole photo-emission with some care to recognize that the excitation energy of the incoming photon is larger.

What about the photo-electrons themselves? The answer depends on where you take them after they leave the material. Do you pull them fully away (to infinity)? In this case, when the frequency of light is constant, photoemission stops. Alternatively, do you give them just enough photo-energy to move to the physical surface of the material and not have them leave to infinite distance? In this case, the photo-electrons are hypothetically present to fall back to the holes and recombine.

The recombination process has its own rules. Recombination may be theoretically unlikely without additional changes in the physical system. For example, if the hole delocalizes in the time that the photo-electron leaves, there is no "hole" left for the recombination process.

Simply put, photoemission is not always a fundamentally-direct reversible process.

So photoelectrons that have not been removed to infinity are left to be attracted to the (delocalized) holes that were left behind. They cannot recombine readily with those holes (photoemission is not a directly reversible process). This build up of photo-electrons creates a negative space-charge above the material. The space charge acts as yet another barrier to removing further photoelectrons. As space charge builds, some electrons can recombine back to the material (through other mechanisms). At some point, for a constant light energy input, an equilibrium steady state is reached where the rate of photoemission into the space charge cloud equals the rate of recombination back to the material.

Suppose that you apply an external electric field potential to try to remove the space-charge photoelectrons. In some cases, the material does not support dissipation of the holes in the material through its own mechanism of internal current flow. You will then also have a positive charge within the material that acts. Any positive potential that you apply to the outside of the material has to overcome the positive field gradient immediately at the surface that points back to the material itself. The spatial extent of charge gradients into the material can be on the order of nanometers. To counter this, you may end up needing large positive potentials in the external field where the distances are larger.

The charge cloud effect is apparent in two types of photo-spectroscopy. In all cases, the samples in photo-emission spectroscopy are connected to a "ground" wire so that electrons can flow in from the outside to make up for the photo-current. In ultra-violet photoemission spectroscopy, the physical systems typically also have to put the samples at a negative voltage level to prevent the build up of overall space charge at the surface (among other reasons). This is because the photo-electrons are excited to low kinetic energy, and they may not have enough extra photo-energy to escape the pull of their own hole without some extra "push". Correspondingly, in x-ray photoemission spectroscopy, when the flux of x-rays on insulators is too high, the insulator cannot pull enough current from the connection wire. The region that is being analyzed builds up a space charge. In this case, one has to reduce the flux of x-rays and/or should have coated the insulator with a conducting metal layer to help dissipate the space charge (by allowing extra current flow along the surface).

Comment: thank you so much. But the question is what happens to space charge does the electron cloud stay there or like it is kept repelled by later photoelectrons. any way thanks sir a lot.

Comment: And also please sir can you tell me why even in a discharge tube space charge is created as the initial electrons come back to the cathode and there is no reason for them stay there as they are not attracted by anything and potential diff. is there to accelerate them.thank you

Comment: I've attempted to explain further. The electrons do not leave the space charge cloud as easily as expected because they are also still under the influence of an attraction to the positive charge density in the material itself (the localized or delocalized holes).

Comment: ohkkkay sir. Now I get it thank you so much sir.